# android HTTP POST error

Tags: android, post, httprequest

Ok so I created a method in a new class and called it from my activity in try catch block, and when I call it and pass my string value my issue appeared...

My issue started after executing the below method after:

```
HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
```

It went to the catch (IOException e) in my activity and when I tried to print the response string it gave me the a response from the server !!!!

So the issue is when I try to pass value to the POST it should return some data but it failed and it's returning the empty message from the server

Hint :
The empty message will appear if there were no values

```
jsonobj.put("screenType", requestString);
```

So did i passed the value or not ??? and why it's causing exception ??

```
public void postData(String requestString) throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
    jsonobj.put("screenType", requestString);
    //jsonobj.put("old_passw", "306");
    HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost("mysite.org");
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
    se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
    httppostreq.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);

    Log.i("in try", httpresponse.toString());
    String responseText=null;

    try {

        responseText=EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("in Exception",e.toString());
        Log.i("arse exception", httpresponse.toString());
    }
}
```

i also added the internet permisssion

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make network requests on the main thread. You'll get the error you are seeing now. You need to use either AsyncTask or you need to create a new thread. Personally, I'd use AsyncTask. When you use AsyncTask you can use the onPostExecute method to return the value to the main thread.

See : [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: i am not doing the call in my first activity its the 2nd  activity

Comment: If you make the call on the  main thread, you catch an error. You must made the call on a background (AsynTaskLoader for example)

Comment: In my firat activity i have one button and when the user click it it will open the camera to read the bar code and from there it will open another activity and in the on create method i am sending the request is it wrong to send it in activity that has layout ????

Answer (score 0):

As vincent said you can't execute network requests in the UI thread, it will give you a weird exception, but rather than using an AsyncTask which will be destroyed if your activity rotates as this [Infographic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/master/gfx/RoboSpice-InfoGraphics.png) shows, I can recommend you to use [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) its the best network framework I have used and it's very easy to use, Good Luck.